# FiddlerCore autoresponder

Tags: fiddlercore

I'm trying to use fiddlercore for vb.net. I'm trying to redirect a url to a different one as how the auto responder would work.  So basically Id do something like if uri.contains(".ashx") redirect traffic too (".png") If that makes any sense

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by reading up on the documentation some more.

Comment: This answer might be valuable to others if you shared your code.